# Can a goalkeeper use his/her hands within the opponents penalty area?

Tags: rules, football, goalkeeper

The [*Wikipedia* article on goalkeepers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goalkeeper#Association_Football) states that:

> The goalkeeper is the only player in the side who may use his or her hands and arms to catch, throw and save the ball, but only **within the penalty area**.

(boldface added, I'v edited the wiki page to solve the ambiguity)

It is however not clear to me whether the goalkeeper can only use his/her hands within the penalty area of his/her team or is he/she allowed to use his/her hands within the penalty area of the opponents team as well.

Sometimes goalkeepers effectively cross the field for instance to assist the team in a final corner, etc. I am wondering if the goalkeeper would be allowed to use his hands (for instance to catch the ball and throw it to the opponents goal?

Can someone provide a reference whether this is allowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [Laws of the Game](http://theifab.com/#!/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/direct-free-kick), Law 12 - Fouls and Misconduct says the following (emphasis mine on first bullet):

> A direct free kick is awarded if a player commits any of the following offences:
>
> - handles the ball deliberately (except for the goalkeeper within **their** penalty area)
> - Holds an opponent
> - impedes an opponent with contact
> - spits at an opponent

In your scenario, the goalkeeper would not be in their own penalty area, but the penalty area of the other team. It would be a foul and the defending team would get a direct free kick.

Comment: Apologies - I hadn't realized I had linked to the 2011 version. I've updated my link!

Answer (score 3):

As [has been pointed out](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/14115/3526), the goalkeeper may only deliberately handle the ball within their own penalty area.

Furthermore, if the goalkeeper attempts to score a goal with their hands in the opponents' penalty area - as is likely in the scenario you have posed - not only would a direct free kick be awarded, but the goalkeeper would also be cautioned (shown the yellow card) for unsporting behaviour.

From the [2016/17 Laws of the Game - 12.3 Disciplinary Action](http://theifab.com/#!/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/disciplinary-action):

> There are different circumstances when a player must be cautioned for unsporting behaviour including if a player:
>
> ...
>
> - handles the ball in an attempt to score a goal (whether or not the attempt is successful) or in an unsuccessful attempt to prevent a goal